# How can I remove remove last few character from text inside div Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Trying to workout how to remove last few characters from text inside div using Javascript.

```
EG: '37  John  Street, Suburb   ABC  20111'

to display: '37  John  Street, Suburb'
```

I used below code but some of the text has multiple whitespaces so it won't work consistently unless it counts 8 characters from the end without including whitespace. The only consistent thing I know is 3 character state and 5 character postcode so 'ABC20111' = 8.

```
<script>
$('#divText').text(function (_,txt) {

    return txt.slice(0, -8);
});
</script>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What's your criteria for removing text? ie. is it the last word? last few letters? last word after a space?

Comment: Removing 3 character state and 5 character postcode. 

EG: ABC 12345 to be removed from the end. The rest doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what other strings look like, you could split the string on `,` and get the first part.

```
$('#divText').text(function (_, txt) { return txt.split(/,/)[0]; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to replace all multiple whitespaces with one using a regex, like:

```
$('#divText').text(function (_,txt) {
   txt = txt.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');
   return txt.slice(0, -8);
});
```

This way you can consistently count from the end, if you also expect trailing whitespaces also use trim:

```
$('#divText').text(function (_,txt) {
  txt = txt.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ').trim();
  return txt.slice(0, -8);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can  use javascript `split` function

Example:

```
var str = '37  John  Street,  Suburb  20111'
var array = str.split(",");
print(array);
```

output : `[37  John  Street,Suburb  20111]`

Answer (score 0):

Below you can see the logic how to get the text you want. Of course you need to transform it in order to fit in your situation.

```
let original_text = '37  John  Street,  ABC  20111'
let text_converted_to_array = original_text.split(' ')
let wanted_text = text_converted_to_array.slice(0, -1).join(' ')
console.log(wanted_text); // outputs:=> 37  John  Street,  ABC
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex you can use:

```
$('#divText').text(function (_,txt) {
    return txt.replace(/,.*[a-z]{3}.*[0-9]{5}/i,'');
});
```

In fact, I just used it on this page, but replaced `#divText` with `prettyprint` and it removed the characters from your original post example.

Explanation of regex:

- `,.*` removes the comma and any whitespace characters (but remove this if you want)
- `[a-z]{3}` removes the three alpha characters for state
- `.*` removes any characters until...
- `[0-9]{5}` removes 5 numeric characters.
- `\i` makes the regex case insensitive.